# React: How to insert my own icon in a VerticalTimelineElement?

Tags: reactjs, image, icons, png, react-component

I want to use my own icon for a VerticalTimelineElement - I import them like so:

`import { myIcon } from "./myIcon.png"`

`import { VerticalTimeline, VerticalTimelineElement } from "react-vertical-timeline-component"`

But I am failing in using it - **I have tried the following ways:**

1: `<VerticalTimelineElement icon={myIcon} key={index} date={item.date}>`
-> I get the response: "export 'myIcon' (imported as 'myIcon') was not found in './myIcon.png' (possible exports: default)"

2: I change my code to import the file:

`import { ReactComponent as MyIcon } from "./myIcon.png"`
and I change the input for the icon inside the Element like so:

`icon={ < MyIcon /> }`
-> I get the response: "export 'ReactComponent' (imported as 'MyIcon') was not found in './myIcon.png' (possible exports: default)"

3: `import MyIcon from "./myIcon.png"` and `icon={MyIcon}`
-> I get: "Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `icon` of type `string` supplied to `VerticalTimelineElement`, expected a single ReactElement."

4: `import MyIcon from "./myIcon.png"` and `icon={<img src={MyIcon} />}`
-> here, I don't even get an error, the picture just does not appear and instead there is that placeholder for when it could not be loaded

I can guarantee that there were no spelling mistakes (I tested myriad times) and I am greatly grateful for any help :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the last option will work, Here is an example [from github](https://github.com/stephane-monnot/react-vertical-timeline/issues/43#issuecomment-568190906)

This is how I managed to do it:

```
import myLogo from './my-logo.png';
```

then in the VerticalTimelineElement component:

```
icon={<img src={myLogo} alt="myLogo" />}
```

This should also work with jpeg, svg

You can look at the source code of the component [here in github](https://github.com/stephane-monnot/react-vertical-timeline/blob/master/src/VerticalTimelineElement.js)

Comment: sorry for the late comment. In any case: thanks for looking into it - but, as written in my Option 4, this does not work for me for some reason -> the image does not load even though it is in the exact same folder and I never had problems with loading images. So your answer does not help me out of my predicament